# Confusion about definition for a valid argument?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In my book it defines "an argument is valid if the premises cannot all be true without the conclusion being true as well."

I had trouble understanding what the author meant ,so I did my best -out of curiosity- to see if I could write that definition in logical form.

This how I tried paraphrase the author's definition of a valid argument:

If the premises are true and the conclusion is true, then the argument is valid, and if the premises are true and conclusion is false, the argument is invalid.

Now here is how I wrote my paraphrase of the author's definition in logical form:

Let P stand for the statement "The premises are true " , C stand for the statement "The conclusion is true", and A stand for the "Argument is valid."

This what my paraphrase in logical form is written:

$[(P\land C)\to A]\land[(P\land\neg C)\to\neg A]$

I do not know if the logical form I created is an accurate representation of what the author wrote as the definition of a valid argument. Do you think it's correct my paraphrase?

Comment: "If the premises are true and the conclusion is true, then the argument is valid" No. One can make invalid arguments for correct conclusions from correct premises. Argument: because I say so.

Comment: @DanielFischer So I'm guessing a better alternative would be to say, "If the premises are true and the conclusion is true, then the argument is _sometimes_ valid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also have a valid argument when one or more of the premises is false. In that case, the truth or falsity of the conclusion changes nothing about the validity of the argument.

Hence, it is correct to say $$(P\land \lnot C) \implies \lnot A.$$

See Wikipedia for more on [when an argument is valid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_argument), which starts:

> In logic, an argument is valid if and only if its conclusion is logically entailed by its premises. A formula is valid if and only if it is true under every interpretation, and an argument form (or schema) is valid if and only if every argument of that logical form is valid.

Note that the linked entry above makes a distinction between a valid argument and a sound argument:

> Validity and soundness
>
> Validity of deduction is not affected by the truth of the premise or the truth of the conclusion. The following deduction is perfectly valid:

```
All animals live on Mars.
All humans are animals.
Therefore, all humans live on Mars.
```

> The problem with the argument is that it is not sound. In order for a deductive argument to be sound, the deduction must be valid and all the premises true.

Comment: I want to understand what we mean when we use the term argument. When we use the term argument, are talking about  all possible scenarios? In addition,  I can have a case where the premises are all false and the conclusion is true, yet the argument is still valid?

Comment: Yes, you can: you might have a valid argument *form* in which one or more of the premises is false, and the conclusion is true. See the added link for clarification.

Comment: Yes. Here's a valid argument with false premises: (P1) The moon is made of green cheese. (P2) I have eight legs. (C) 1=1. It is valid because the premises cannot be true and the conclusion false; it is *never* the case that $1 \not = 1$. The sense of argument here is very abstract; just a set of sentences as premises and a sentence as a conclusion.

Comment: "The only scenario that makes an argument NOT valid is when the premises are all true, but the conclusion is false. In all other scenarios, the argument is valid." Not so. Validity requires it to be NECESSARILY the case that if the premisses are true the conclusion is too.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, thank you. But I had already revised the post, as you can see.

Comment: @amWhy I reread the edit to the post of your answer. So, in the case of mathematics, all that matters is if the argument is only valid?And in  the case of real life (like a lawyer), the argument must be sound and valid? Correct me if I am wrong, or I need to be more clear.

Comment: Generally, mathematics is also (usually) most interested in  sound arguments. Entailment, or necessity, as Peter Smith points out, is what's crucial to validity. Do the premises (if true) necessarily imply that the conclusion must be true.

Comment: @amWhy You quoted from the wiki,"The problem with the argument is that it is not sound. In order for a deductive argument to be sound, the deduction must be valid and all the premises true."So, ($P\land \lnot C) \implies \lnot A$ is good definition for an argument, that is an argument that is sound and valid. Once more, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: True premises and false conclusion automatically makes an argument invalid, hence not sound. Soundness requires validity, but more: the argument must be (1) valid, and $(2)$ the premises and conclusion implied by the premises must all be true.

Comment: @PeterSmith There does NOT exist anything which forces the inferences in any given theory (though it may hold for some theories), since the rules of inference can come as metalogical.  If the premises hold as true, *if you also accept the rules of inference as valid* also, if the argument comes as valid also, then the conclusion will hold as true.  In plenty of logical theories, without rules of inference, validity comes as impossible.